# Como remover esse azul de seleção ao gerar o PDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, html2pdf-js

Tenho um sistema que faz marcações no texto, criando um span com as notas, estou utilizando uma lib para exportar PDF, porém quando ele carrega o DOM para exportar para PDF, ele está mantendo essa marca azul de seleção, muito estranho. Tem alguma maneira de travar esse evento de "selection" no texto ao mandar exportar o pdf?

[Aqui a HTML](https://gist.github.com/ivanferrer/986984ea2c69500304c85088aeedc729) que é enviada para gerar o PDF.

Esta é a [Lib](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js).

Este é o código que pega essa HTML:

```
var content = "aqui entra como string o conteúdo do link acima";

var worker =  html2pdf();

                        worker.set(opt)
                        .from(content)
                        .toPdf()
                        .get('pdf')
                        // 
                        .then(function (doc) {

                          var totalPages = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
                          for (var i=1; i<=totalPages; i++) {

                           if (i == 1) {
                             doc.setPage(1);
                             //cria a legenda
                              doc.setFontType("bold");
                              doc.text(330, 40, 'Matéria: ');
                              doc.setFontType("normal");
                              doc.text(380, 40,  'No onno nono nononono');

                              doc.setFontType("bold");
                              doc.text(330, 60, 'Atividade: ');
                              doc.setFontType("normal");
                              doc.text(390, 60, 'Nonnono onno nonono');
                              doc.setFontSize(12);
                              doc.setFontType("normal");
                              doc.setPage(i);
                           } else {
                               doc.setPage(i);

                           }

                          }


                        })

                        .save();
```

Veja o problema que está ocorrendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pq que na hora da exportação vc não força um .focus() em um elemento que esteja fora da tela por exemplo? Ou então muda a cor do ::selection para transparente para testar

Comment: Então, eu já tentei `.blur()` nos elementos , `.focusout()`, `.focus()` return false; e nada...

Comment: Não entendo porque isso acontece? Não faz muito sentido, além disso, era pra estar com cor no texto, e não pegou...